# Generic where clause in class: 'Failure' is not a member type of type 'Self'

Tags: swift, generics, combine

Why does `Self.Failure` result in an error when `AddIndexPublisher` is defined as a class, but shows no error when defined as a struct?

Consider the following: (compile errors shown in comments above the corresponding line)

```swift
class AddIndexPublisher<InputP: Publisher>: Publisher {
    typealias Output = (InputP.Output, Int)
    typealias Failure = InputP.Failure

    let ip: InputP

    init(ip: InputP) {
        self.ip = ip
    }

    func receive<S>(subscriber: S)
    // 'Failure' is not a member type of type 'Self'
    // 'Output' is not a member type of type 'Self'
    where S : Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input
    {
        let sub = AddIndexSubscription<
                        // 'Failure' is not a member type of type 'Self'
                        S, InputP, Self, InputP.Output, Self.Failure
                    >(sub: subscriber, ipub: ip, opub: self)
        subscriber.receive(subscription: sub)
    }
}
```

Removing `Self.` lets the compile errors disappear too when using `class`. However, I'm curious why there is a difference between struct and class producing these errors. Is there a section in the spec which explains some background for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My base idea is on 2 points:

1. Has to do with inheritance, since structs can't inherit from other structs. This also connects to point 2.
2. `Self.Failure` is using `Self`, which is a type (in this case, of the current same object type). Also `Output` and `Failure` are associated types of the `Publisher` protocol. Using `Self` of associated types doesn't make sense due to inheritance of classes( what types really are these `Failure` and `Output` ?). Removing `Self.` tells the compiler to use the typealias defined in this object.

It's a nice question anyway, thanks for this :)